# Bounds on update time in the RMQ problem subject to $O(1)$ query time?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

In the static RMQ problem, one has to answer queries about the minimum in a range of a fixed array. A classic variation allows updates of the form $A_i \leftarrow x $.

My question is : How fast can we update if we must answer queries in $O(1)$?

I can think of a solution which works in $O(\sqrt{n})$ per update :

We can answer queries in $O(1)$ using a sparse table. Since each element is a part of $O(n)$ ranges in the sparse table, we can clearly update a sparse table of an array of size $n$ in $O(n)$. Now, divide into $\sqrt{n}$ blocks. For each block, maintain the prefix and suffix minimums and also a sparse table. Clearly, a block can be updated in $O(\sqrt{n})$. On the upper level, maintain another sparse table which can answer minimum over a range of blocks. Clearly this can also be done in $O(\sqrt{n})$  and the query time is still $O(1)$. The memory used and precomputation done are both $O(n \log{n})$.

Can we do better, say $\text{polylog}(n)$, perhaps using more memory and/or precomputation? Is there a known lower bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide the whole range into $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$ blocks, and for each block apply your $O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$ approach. Then you can get $O\left(\sqrt{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}+n^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)=O\left(n^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$ update time with constant query time.

Recursively, you can get $O\left(n^\epsilon\right)$ update time with constant query time for any **constant** $\epsilon>0$.